# I need to run fsck on a remotely hosted Ubuntu 18.04 VM

Tags: read-only

I have a headless Odoo server running on Ubuntu 18.04 VM in a remote location run by Windows admins. My / is in a Read-Only state, so touching /forcefsck just replies back cannot touch...: Read-Only file system.

Are there any reboot parameters I can call on the reboot or shutdown -r commands that'll add the forcefsck to the restart? or any other way of getting my system backup and running proper?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameters and other data cannot be passed through a reboot.

You will need the assistance of those Windows admins to reach GRUB, then a recovery console where you can run fsck.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation